# GCP BigQuery - Verify successful execution of stored procedure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

I have a BigQuery routine that inserts records into a BQ Table.
I am looking to have a Eventarc trigger that triggers Cloud Run, and performs some action on successful execution of the BigQuery Routine.

From Cloud Logging, I can see two events that would seem to confirm the successful execution of the BQ Routine.
`protoPayload.methodName="google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob"`

> protoPayload.metadata.tableDataChange.insertedRowsCount

However, this does not give me the Job ID.

So, I am looking at event -
`protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"`

Would it be correct to assume that, if `protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatus.error` is empty, then the stored procedure execution was successful?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try using `protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.insert"`? This contains `jobID`, `error count` (if there's any) and `jobstatus`.

Comment: A job (i.e. a query) call your stored procedure. Therefore, if the job is OK, the store procedure is also OK!

Comment: Hi @loki, is your query resolved?

Comment: Thanks all for the help; I am using `protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"` as the approach, as it gives the `State` and `resourceName` as required for the purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with `protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"` in this case.
It gives the job id at `protoPayload.requestMetadata.resourceName`, status like `protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatus.state` and errors if any like `protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobStatus.error`